# dragenter/dragleave prevents drop from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

my problem is, that when I use *dragenter* and *dragleave* the *drop*-event is no longer fired. When I change the *dragenter* to ***dragover*** it works. But I want to reduce the fired events by using *drageneter*. Any ideas?

```
$("#drop")
  .on("drop", function(event) {
    $("#debug").append("drop\n")
   })
  .on("dragenter", function (event) {
    $("#debug").append("dragover\n")
   })
  .on("dragleave", function (event) {
    $("#debug").append("dragleave\n")
   })

  .on("dragover", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
   });
```

I also tried to cancel the default events with `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` but it didn't change anything.

Here is a simplified code: https://jsfiddle.net/7oun2gza/

**Edit:** Just found the solution by myself. I have to disable the default events in the *dragover* to shoot a *drop*-event. Fixed the code above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that I have to **disable the default of dragover** to fire the drop-event. I fixed the code in my question.